# Kernel of restriction map in Galois cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, galois-representations, galois-cohomology

Let $S$ be the algebraic group $SL_2/\mathbb{Q}_p$ with a $G=G_{\mathbb{Q}}$ action, (acts by conjugation with a representation $\rho: G\longrightarrow GL_2$.)

Let $G_p$ be the decomposition group at the place $p$, and consider the restriction map:

$H^1(G,S)\longrightarrow H^1(G_p, S)$.

I am trying to understand how to compute its kernel. I imagine there is some way to compute it which is functorial in $S$.

EDIT: I guess I would be just as interested if $S$ is replaced by an arbitrary $G$-module, $M$.

Comment: These things are known. Please write your question nicely: what are $S$, $G$, $G_p$, $\rho$.  After that, I will try to answer your question.

Comment: You ask a lot of "slightly unnatural" looking questions.

Comment: Is this comment refering to Mikhail or me? J/K. Either way, this has to do with the fact that I switched fields from complexity to analytic number theory to arithmetic geometry, which means that my knowledge of the literature and use of language is lacking.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi I understand this kernel should, somehow, be computed using the Hochschield-Serre spectral sequence. Could you explain to me how exactly?